# Contact Form Plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I'm currently using Contact Form 7 as my form's plugin, but I need the form to be submitted to a "thank you" page on success, in order to be able to track my objectives in Google Analytics. As Contact Form 7 uses AJAX to post the form, I'm not able to track a "message sent" event...

Do you know about any plugin with this capabilities? Much better if it's free...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Contact Form 7 blog post](http://contactform7.com/blog/2009/11/24/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/) linked from the [Contact Form 7 FAQ](http://contactform7.com/faq/) shows you how to track form submissions as an Analytics target.

Basically you hook into CF7's on_sent_ok hook and call Analytics' _trackPageview() method. That lets you fire off any given Analytics target whenever the form is sucessfully submitted without needing redirection to a "thank you" page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GravityForms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) - simple to use, nice interface, tons of configuration options. Not free, but will save you a ton of time.

You can also try [TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) (free) but I think development was discontinued by its author.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this today actually: [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com). Very robust site and free for low usage (100 submissions/mo).

They have instructions for embedding with wordpress: http://jotform.com/help/4-Adding-Forms-to-Wordpress.

Good luck!